# Complex numbers problem with large exponents

Tags: complex-numbers

> I have to simplify the following complex number: $\Big(\dfrac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{1-i}\Big)^{20}$

The solution I've been given is $2^9 (1-i\sqrt{3})$ but I don't know how to get it.

I know how to simplify $\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{1-i}$ on its own but I'm not able to simplifiy the same expression with the exponent.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: consider writing binomial expression for $(1-i)^{20}$... before that compute $(1-i)^2,(1-i)^3,(1-i)^4$...

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to use polar coordinates in which case
$$1+\sqrt{3}i=2\exp{\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\cdot i\right)}$$
$$1-i=\sqrt{2}\exp{\left(-\frac{\pi}{4}\cdot i\right)}$$
Which gives a quotient of
$$\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{1-i}=\sqrt{2}\exp{\left(\frac{7\pi}{12}\cdot i\right)}$$
and hence raising to the power of $20$ gives
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{1-i}\right)^{20}
&=\left(\sqrt{2}\exp{\left(\frac{7\pi}{12}\cdot i\right)}\right)^{20}\\
&=2^{10}\exp{\left(\frac{35\pi}{3}\cdot i\right)}\\
&=2^{10}\left(\frac12-\frac{\sqrt{3}}2\cdot i\right)\\
&=2^9\left(1-\sqrt{3}i\right)\\
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your speedy response but by any chance do you know how to do it in Rectangular Form?

Comment: Maybe note that we have$$(1+\sqrt{3}i)^3=-8\qquad(1-i)^4=-4$$and hence the result is given by$$\frac1{1+\sqrt{3}i}\cdot\frac{(-8)^7}{(-4)^5}$$

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

$$\left(\dfrac{1+i\sqrt3}2\right)^{20}=\left(\left(\dfrac{1+i\sqrt3}2\right)^3\right)^6\left(\dfrac{1+i\sqrt3}2\right)^2=(-1)^6\left(\dfrac{-1+i\sqrt3}2\right)$$

$$\left(\dfrac{1-i}{\sqrt2}\right)^{20}=\left(\left(\dfrac{1-i}{\sqrt2}\right)^{2}\right)^{10}=(-i)^{10}=-1$$